# Quartz: can't create a rounded rectangle with gradient fill

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm at the point of starting to tear my hair off. I'm trying to create a gradient fill covering the area of rectangle with rounded corners. This is the code I have in my `drawRect:`:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

CGFloat c = BUBBLE_INSET + BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS;

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, BUBBLE_INSET, c);

CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_INSET, c, BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);    
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - c, BUBBLE_INSET);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, c, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - c);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.width - c, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, c, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - c, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);

CGContextClosePath(ctx);

CGContextClip(ctx);

CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:color1, color2, nil];

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);

CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, p1, p2, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
```

This code draws an empty white rectangle. Path is built correctly (I tried invoking `CGContextFillPath()` and the result is nicely filled with solid color), `color1` and `color2` values are correct (seen in debugger). What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you sure, that color1 and color2 are defined in RGB-Space. i.e.[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor] returns a monochrome spaced-color.

Comment: It turned out that color1 and color2 are of type UIColor, which is totally wrong. Added `CGColor` invocation where needed and things are working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that color1 and color2 were of type `UIColor`, which is totally wrong. Changed the line

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:color1, color2, nil];
```

to

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[color1 CGColor], [color2 CGColor], nil];
```

and got the result I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your colors are wrapped the colors array.

Try using

```
CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
```

instead.

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

CGFloat c = BUBBLE_INSET + BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS;

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, BUBBLE_INSET, c);

CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_INSET, c, BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);    
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - c, BUBBLE_INSET);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, c, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - c);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width - BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.width - c, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, c, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - BUBBLE_INSET, BUBBLE_INSET, rect.size.height - c, BUBBLE_CORNER_RADIUS);

CGContextClosePath(ctx);

CGContextClip(ctx);

CGGradientRef gradient;
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  // Start color
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.65 }; // End color

rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, p1, p2, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
```

You'll get this:

offset was 5.0
radius was 10.0

[image]